# Prove these quadractic forms are equivalent over $\mathbb{Z_5}$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

Consider the following quadractic forms, defined in the field $\mathbb{Z_5}$,

$$q(x, y, z, t) = 2y^2 + z^2 + 2t^2 + 4xy + 2xt + 4yt$$
$$q_0(x, y, z, t) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + dt^2$$

Prove they are equivalent for some $d\in\mathbb{Z_5}$.

Now, what I've done is, I've diagonalized the first quadractic form, which yields $diag(1,-2,2,\frac{1}{2})$. The second one is already in diagonal form, since its matrix is $diag(1,1,1,d)$.

To simplify things, the matrix of the first quadratic form can be simplied by the congruent matrix $diag(1,2,2,3)$.

Now, to prove they are equivalent, I'd have to show the matrices are congruent for some value $d\in\mathbb{Z_5}$, but I have no clue how to do this. Could you provide me with some suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer. I know that if they only differ in a quadratic residue, then they are congruent, but I know nothing regarding the reciprocal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hmm, wait a sec, if $diag(2,2)$ is congruent with $diag(1,1)$, and since the first entry in both diagonal matrices is equal to $1$, would that imply that by using $d=3$, both matrices are equivalent? Also, how did you gauge the required matrix to find that congruence?

Comment: @LMartin: Yes, exactly. I found it by some not entirely systematic exploration of possible ways to achieve $({}^{a\,b}_{c\,d})({}^{a\,c}_{b\,d})=({}^x{}_y)$. Note however, that _in the reals_ the basis change employed here corresponds to a 45° turn and a scaling with a factor of $\sqrt2$...